# Android AVD Cannot Create AVD - Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, android-virtual-device

The "OK" button does nothing when trying to create the new AVD. There are no errors. I have uninstalled the software and reinstalled, but it is the same thing. I have the latest version of everything so I cannot figure out how to do this.

[image: Settings]

There is a screenshot of the settings.

Please help as I am trying to do a course on android development as I am pretty new to it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a known bug see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661. You can start the AVD Manager from outside Eclipse, it then works, but takes quite a while to create and to start. Be patient.

Comment: Hello !

I've been throught this error and no mattter if i was in eclipse or not it didn't work.

I just needed to install the packages of the APIs from the Android SDK Manager and everything was okay after ;)